# Both List and ArrayList remove method doesn't work

Tags: java, arraylist

Today I have an even more stupid problem than yesterday but I really can't understand why my code doesn't work.

The code is the following:

```
public class A{
    List fileList;

    public A(List fl){
        fileList = new ArrayList<String>;
        if(fl != null) {
            fileList = fl;
        }
    }

    public void removeFiles(List fl){
        for(Object obj : fl) {
            fileList.remove(obj.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried every single things I found on the web even with an `Iterator` but no file has been removed and no errors or exceptions comes up!

> Some more code

```
public class CoordinationServer extends Activatable implements CoordinationSerInt
{
List<CoordObj> userList;
public int updateFileList(String username, List files, int option) throws RemoteException{
    for (CoordObj anUserList : userList) {
        if (anUserList.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            if(option == 0){
                anUserList.setFileList(files);
                return 1;

            }else if(option == 1){
                anUserList.addFilesToList(files);
                return 1;

            }else if(option == 2){
                anUserList.removeFiles(files);
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
}

public class CoordObj implements Serializable
{
UserForUser userReference;
List fileList;
String username;

public CoordObj(UserForUser ur, List fl, String un) {
  userReference = ur;
  fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
  if(fl != null)
    fileList = fl;
  username = un;
}

public void removeFiles(List fl){
  this.fileList.removeAll(fl);
}
}
```

**RESOLVED**
If someone else has this problem I resolved it in this way:

```
fileList.removeAll(Arrays.asList(fl.toArray()));
```

Comment: You should be able to use `fileList.removeAll(fl)` too, rather than implementing your own loop. See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: @Phylogenesis: or `fileList.clear()`.

Comment: still nothing...tried fileList.removeAll(fl) but it still doesn't remove nothing..

Comment: @staticx The `removeFiles()` method takes a `List` as a parameter. It doesn't necessarily follow that the `ArrayList` is to be cleared.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Depends on what you want to do.. It wasn't clear from OP's example but he commented on my answer that he wants just what is in the passed in list.

Comment: What do You want to do ? Remove entry from list or remove file from filesystem ?

Comment: fileList contains a list of file's name, fl contains file's name selected from fileList. So what I want to do is to remove all names contained in fl from fileList

Answer (score 9):

you are calling the objects toString() method, don't do that. Just use the [object itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
for(Object obj:fl){
  fileList.remove(obj);
}
```

Which will remove everything from the list btw, so you could just do [clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear%28%29).

Comment: can't do clear() or the whole fileList is erased! I just want to delete the fl files that are in the fileList too...

Comment: @Irith look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: I suspect the real issue lies in the fact that he's generating new elements for the `removeFiles()` call and it is failing because object comparison in Java doesn't perform deep checking.

Comment: @Phylogenesis i agree actually as toString() on a string just returns the same string(?) so the internal equals call should work as expected.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Yes, just tested.

Comment: 7 upvotes for an incorrect answer, I have correct answers in minus figures :-/

Comment: still can't make it work...the funny thing is that add method works perfectly but remove doesn't...

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong

```
fileList = new ArrayList<String>;
```

change this to

```
 fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't throw an error or exception. Per the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29), it is optional to throw a `ClassCastException`, which `List` won't throw. It also states that **"..if this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged..."**. Therefore, the operation essentially is a no-op.

Use `fileList.removeAll(fl)` to remove everything that is to be removed from `fileList`. No loop needed. `removeAll` returns `true` if `fileList` was changed, so you can check if the operation was successful or not.

Comment: Only the elements which are contend of the argument `List fl` shell be deleted.

Comment: @ifLoop: Then use `removeAll`.

Answer (score 0):

while you declaring you list with `String` type, you can just do:

```
fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

 for(String str : fl){
      fileList.remove(str);
 }
```